# Light going through edges of wall?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

So i started just recently learning Blender so keep that in mind.
I'm modeling a house and in Eevee rendered mode seems like light is coming in where my two walls meet.I checked for double edges, checked the normals and could not find the error. Yes my walls and floor are different objects and stacked on top of each other by eye but that could be the problem only for the bottom light intrusion. Ill add pictures so you better understand.[image]

[image]

Any help welcome AF! Thank you!

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Try to use 'contact shadows' in the light object properties.

Comment: This is what is called peter-panning. Contact shadows can help as @lemon says. Thicker walls is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Select the light you have -> properties editor->enable shadows and enable contact shadows in it.[image]

It is only necessary for cycles render engine

Answer (score 0):

When this has happened to me, I was always able to fix it by being sure lines/faces were in fact touching and parallel. I found the "snap" tool was essential in making this happen.

Comment: I was having the same problem  I saw this answer and tried it out on my scene.  However, I had to change some settings under Shadow as well.  I had to put the Clip Start to 1.5 m and Contact Shadows>Distance to 1.2 m to get rid of the shadows coming through the wall.

Comment: you will also want to turn up Bias, or else you may get weird dark triangles on your mesh due to the distance setting you changed